# Whats the difference between Mail and EmailAddress

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

When I run a command below using Active Directory Module we get mail, EmailAddress attribute. What's the difference between them and why do they exist. I am asking this in terms of ActiveDirectory and Exchange.

`Get-AdUser TestUser -Server Test.com -properties * | FL SamAccountName, Mail, EmailAddress`

**Output:**
SamAccountName : TestUser
mail           : TestUser@Test.com
EmailAddress   : TestUser@Test.com

Comment: `EmailAddress` is PowerShell's friendly representation of the LDAP `mail` attribute. In AD, the property name is `mail` (LDAPDisplayName)

Comment: @Theo.Thanks a lot. Could you please lead me to any of Microsoft article which talks about such attributes?

Comment: Sure, [MS Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx) has always been a great help to me.

Comment: @Theo. Bingo.. For me its really hard to find one. Thanks. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped!